# Running a function in a for loop and adding the returned dataframe to a list in R

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe

I have a function that takes in one argument as a particular year. This function returns a dataframe. Now I want to create a for loop for a range of years and add these data frames to a list or to combine into a large dataframe.

Will something like this help:

```
l <- list()
for (year in 2010:2017) {l <- functionX(subset(dataset, Year==year))}
```

It's not working. The error I get is-

*longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length*

I also tried calling the function just as :

```
functionX(subset(dataset, Year== 2010:2017))
```

This doesn't work either.

Edit:

I think because the lengths of the data frames for each year are not same, hence they're not getting added. I made a slight change-

```
for (i in 2010:2017) {
  df <- functionX(subset(dataset, Year==i))
  l[i] <- df$Name

  }
```

*Error:
 number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length*

I'm not trying to replace, but just trying to add elements of a particular dataframe for each year to the list.

Comment: Ok, I just changed it and reposted the error

Answer (score 0):

I updated your example to make it reproducible. The general idea is as follows: inside the `for` loop you put your `data.frame` inside a list. Then you append that list to the big list, `l`. That way your `data.frame` becomes an element inside of the list `l`:

```
l <- list()
functionX <- function(Year) {
  set.seed(Year)
  df <- data.frame(year=Year, x=rnorm(10))
  return(df)
}

for (year in 2010:2011) {
  l <- functionX(year) ## this will not error, but will just overwrite l on every loop
}

l
#>    year           x
#> 1  2011 -0.65480083
#> 2  2011 -0.02877456
#> 3  2011 -0.19413575
#> 4  2011 -0.90141523
#> 5  2011  1.31329723
#> 6  2011 -0.82243619
#> 7  2011 -0.25875645
#> 8  2011  0.23465318
#> 9  2011 -0.42060734
#> 10 2011 -0.63676356

l <- list()
for (year in 2010:2011) {
  new_l <- list(functionX(year)) ## this will put the resulting df as an element in a list
  l <- append(l, new_l)          ## this appends the lists together
  }

l
#> [[1]]
#>    year            x
#> 1  2010 -0.537472741
#> 2  2010 -0.005191135
#> 3  2010  1.005671811
#> 4  2010  0.214009870
#> 5  2010 -0.201253144
#> 6  2010  1.447430260
#> 7  2010 -0.539834711
#> 8  2010 -1.520636908
#> 9  2010  0.652780491
#> 10 2010  0.613471135
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    year           x
#> 1  2011 -0.65480083
#> 2  2011 -0.02877456
#> 3  2011 -0.19413575
#> 4  2011 -0.90141523
#> 5  2011  1.31329723
#> 6  2011 -0.82243619
#> 7  2011 -0.25875645
#> 8  2011  0.23465318
#> 9  2011 -0.42060734
#> 10 2011 -0.63676356
```

Created on 2018-08-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Comment: Thanks, JD. Let me make the changes and see....yes, it was replacing the list and casing an error since the lists are not of same length.....

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do what you want.

First, I will create a test dataset, since you have not posted one.

```
set.seed(527)    # make the results reproducible
dataset <- data.frame(Year = sample(2000:2018, 100, TRUE), X = rnorm(100))
```

Now the function.

```
functionX <- function(DF, years){
  res <- lapply(years, function(y) subset(DF, Year == y))
  names(res) <- years
  res
}

functionX(dataset, 2010:2017)
```